# SQL Server tells me that I have to declare scalar variable

Tags: sql-server

> I'm using a table with this variables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_details(
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  username varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  first_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  gender varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  password varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  status INT DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

To that point, everything is cool. But when I want to create a Procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pruebita
@pkk INT
@statitus INT
AS
UPDATE user_details SET status = status+@statitus
WHERE status  @pkk=status;
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure pruebita, Line 22 Incorrect
>   syntax near '@statitus'. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure
>   pruebita, Line 24 Must declare the scalar variable "@statitus".

I've entered `DECLARE` before `@pkk` and `@statitus` and that don't solve the error. You know how to solve this?

Comment: "I'm using a table with this variables:" - tables do not ahve variables, they have fields or columns.

Comment: *"`WHERE status  @pkk=status`"* That doesn't make sense. Looks like a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma between your parameters.  Also, you normally put parentheses around the parameters. Also, did you mean to compare @pkk to status or the user id

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pruebita(
@pkk INT,
@statitus INT)
AS
UPDATE user_details SET status = status+@statitus
WHERE @pkk=status;
```